# Advantages of HTTP4 component in camel

Tags: apache-camel

Can any one give some brief about advantages of HTTP4/HTTPS4 component in camel over http component.

In which case we need to choose which component?

Answer (score 7):

The HTTP component uses the Apache [HTTP client v.3](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/), which is end of life. The HTTP4 component uses [v.4.x](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) of the HTTP client component, which is actively maintained. So if you start fresh, then you should use the http4 component.

EDIT: Camel 3 discontinued the legacy HTTP client support. The Camel http component (without the 4) is now based on version 4.5 of the Apache http components client. The Camel HTTP4 component has been removed.